# "Bonemerging" one armature to another

Tags: rigging, objects, armature, interface, constraints

I have two armatures, A and B. A and B share some bones. What I want to do is, for the bones that A and B share, for all matching bones in B to be automatically set to the position of the corresponding bone, with the same name, in A, while keeping both armatures seperate. This is so I can adjust the positioning of the bones on A. This is something Source Engine does called "Bonemerging", and I would like to be able to adjust the position of my bones while seeing how it will affect another bonemerged model.

Basically, I want to be see how a model will look after it has been bonemerged to another in Blender.

Comment: Did you try setting a copy transform bone constraint (local space - local space) on every "merged" bone?

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks a bunch.